# For loop doesn't continue after using readline question

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

I want to loop x amount of times while doing a readline each time. In my code after reading in the first input, the loop never moves onto the second iteration. I assume it has something to do with the inline function I created but I'm stuck as to why. Any help?

```js
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});
rl.question("Ok how many players will there be (MAX: 8 players)\n", function(playerCount) {
  const parsedInput = parseInt(playerCount);
  if (parsedInput > 0 && parsedInput <= 8) {
    let listOfNames = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < parsedInput; i++) {
      rl.question(`Enter name #${i}\n`, function gatherNames(name) {
        listOfNames.push(name);
        console.log(`Added ${name} to list of players\n`);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Please post valid code, you're missing the `)` at the end of the `rl.question(` function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `rl.question(...)` `parsedInput` times, before you even enter the response from the first one. The library doesn't seem to support that and just silently fails.

You need to call the next `rl.question(...)` only after you received response from the current question.
For that you will need to call in inside the callback and can't use the `for` loop. You will need to rely on the size of the `listOfNames` array to know when to stop.

```
readline = require("readline");

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
});
rl.question("Ok how many players will there be (MAX: 8 players)\n", function(playerCount) {
    const parsedInput = parseInt(playerCount);
    if (parsedInput > 0 && parsedInput <= 8) {
        let listOfNames = [];
        const add_name = function(name) {
            listOfNames.push(name);
            console.log(`Added ${name} to list of players\n`);
            // if the array doesn't have the desired number of names, ask again.
            if (listOfNames.length < parsedInput) {
                rl.question(`Enter name #${listOfNames.length}\n`, add_name);
            }
            // else print them out and end it
            else {
                console.log(listOfNames)
                rl.close();
            }
        }
        rl.question(`Enter name #0\n`, add_name);
    }
});
```

A better approach would be with async/await code i.e. promises.
It would make extending the functionally a lot simpler and straight forward.
The flow of the code is a lot closer to what you have tried.

```
const readlinePromises = require('readline/promises');

const rl = readlinePromises.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
});
(async () => {
    const playerCount = await rl.question("Ok how many players will there be (MAX: 8 players)\n");
    const parsedInput = parseInt(playerCount);
    if (parsedInput > 0 && parsedInput <= 8) {
        let listOfNames = [];
        for (let i=0; i<parsedInput; i++) {
            const name = await rl.question(`Enter name #${i}\n`);
            listOfNames.push(name);
            console.log(`Added ${name} to list of players\n`);
        }
        console.log(listOfNames);
    }
    rl.close();
})();
```